# Extension like angular2-switcher for Visual Studio 2017

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2017

I'm using angular 6 in Visual Studio 2017 (not visual studio code). I want go with shortcut by keyboard in `.ts`, `.html` and `.css` files. In visual studio code "**angular2-switcher**" and "**file-ext-switcher**" doing this. Are there any extension for Visual studio 2017?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My [Tabs Studio](https://tabsstudio.com/) extension has the **TabsStudio.OpenCorrespondingFile** command that opens related files with the same name. You can assign a keyboard shortcut to it in Visual Studio keyboard options.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @SergeyVlasov. This product doing what I want and it is good product. But, 49$ very expensive for my country for personal usage.

Answer (score 0):

This extension [Angular Html TS Switcher](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OAS.593771d0-13b5-4de6-a192-165dd6f16144) is support visual studio 2019 and supported for visual studio 2017 still in progress , but if you interested you can add [new issue her](https://github.com/OsamaAbuSitta/AngularVSExtension/issues).

Update: For visual studio 2022 you can use this version [Angular Html TS Switcher](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OAS.05D8FE2B-55EC-4A28-8865-C2570F30A1C9)